# How to catch resizing of TR element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have table like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="myRow>
        <td>aaa bbb ccc</td>
        <td>aaa bbb ccc</td>
        <td>aaa bbb ccc</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- few another rows -->
</table>
```

I don't fix height of TR element. So, height of TR can be changed if user resizes browser window or if cells content is being modified by JavaScript.
How can I catch the moment when height of TR is changed?

**UPDATE**: it seems to be that `height` is not valid attribute for `tr` element. So, now my question is: how to catch resizing of `td` element?

Comment: What do you want to do when the height changes? There might be a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: @JohnFx much agreed, normally if you have to rely on something like a resize handler, there should already be some adaptable mechanism in place (such as flexible CSS sizing, etc)

Comment: Also, I don't think height is a valid attribute of a TR element, so you might be out of luck. You might have to do it on one of the TD cells inside it.

Comment: @JohnFx: the whole problem is a bit more complicated. Table has two rows. The second row of my table contains scrollable div. And I need to change the size of this div when either the size of the table is changed (it is 100% of the browser window clientsize) or height of the first table row is changed. I can handle resizing of browser window but I don't know how to handle resizing of the first row.

Comment: So, it's not necessary TR. TD resizing event will also help me.

Comment: So essentially you need a scrollable div that takes up the remaining space on the page (minus the first row). Is that correct? If so you can do this with a pure CSS solution and no script.

Answer (score 2):

Height isn't a valid attribute on a TR element, so you are probably out of luck unless you find a way to check for the resize on a TD element inside it.

If you are trying to detect the change to do some other layout corrections there is probably a better way using CSS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jQuery's [resize binding](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) could help

But why exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: But "The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes" so the "resize" event won't be triggered if the table changes size because content was added or removed.

Comment: This event is supposed to be triggered on window resize, where you could then resize your td's accordingly. As per the above posts, resizing the height based on content change is something that would only seem to be an issue if your CSS is not well-though-out.

Comment: I have to adjust height of another element when height of this TR is changed. CSS is not goood for it.